# Function in update is called only once

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Game should freeze for every 200 score gained and a quiz will appear. After answering it, the game should resume.
In my code it happens only once. After incrementing the freezescore to 400 for the next quiz to appear, the game doesn't freeze.

```
public static int freezescore = 200;

void Update () 
{
    if (score == freezescore)
    {
        freeze();
        Quiz();
        Debug.Log("" + freezescore);
    }
}

public bool freeze()
{
    Time.timeScale = 0.1f;
    return true;
}

public void Quiz()
{
    if (freeze() == true)
    {
        if (canvasquiz != null)
        {
            canvasquiz.SetActive(true);
        }

    }
}

//Attached this method to the button
public void Resume()
{
    if (canvasquiz != null)
    {
        canvasquiz.SetActive(false);
        Time.timeScale = 1.0f;
    }

    score = score + 1;
    freezescore = freezescore + 200;
}
```

Comment: Why do you need `freeze()` to return `bool` if it always return `true`. You can make it `void`.Also, could you show how `Update()` method is called?

Comment: Is this a MonoBehavior? Is update getting called every frame? Generally speaking, this whole setup has a bad smell to it - I'd expect the behavior you're trying to create to be event driven rather than per-frame. Anyway - did you set breakpoints? What value is freezescore actually at when your script fails? What does the condition evaluate to?

Comment: You're also calling freeze() twice: once before Quiz() and then in Quiz() again. That doesn't make sense. Maybe you want to set a field boolean to true and then check against that?

Comment: Finally: are there other ways to increment the score variable? Because you increment that by 1, but the freezescore by 200. And if you can't gain score elsewhere, score can never catch up to freezescore.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, I would rewrite this a little:

```
private int freezeScore;
private int score;

private void Update()
{
    if (score >= freezeScore)
    {
        StartQuiz();
    }
}

public void StartQuiz()
{
    Time.timeScale= 0;
    if (canvasquiz != null)
    {
        canvasquiz.SetActive(true);
    }
}

//Attatch to button
public void EndQuiz()
{
    if (canvasquiz != null)
    {
        canvasquiz.SetActive(false);
        Time.timeScale = 1.0f;
    }
    score += 1;

    freezeScore += 200;
}
```

This is untested as I don't have all your code, so you might have to modify it a little, but I hope you get the idea.

There are a few reasons that things might not have been working the way you had them:

`if (score == freezescore)` in the `Update` function would mean that if the player gained more than one point at any time then they might miss out 200, 400, or 600 and so on, meaning `Quiz` wouldn't trigger.

Also, I don't know why the `freeze` function was returning a bool and being checked when it always returned true. The `if (freeze() == true)` statement in `Quiz` would always be true. You would be as well just setting the timescale in the `Quiz` function.